# Rsync (or ssh) to a remote docker container on EC2

Tags: networking, ssh, docker, amazon-ec2, rsync

Because rsync uses ssh to transfer files, I think this boils down to being able to ssh into my docker container remotely.

I currently have a base centos:6.6 docker container running with port forwarding from 2222->22:

```
IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS
a374fd62f97f        "/bin/bash"         2 hours ago         Up 2 hours          0.0.0.0:2222->22/tcp
```

I can ssh into the server running the docker service using

```
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@PUBLIC_IP
```

From my EC2 instance, after installing openssh-server in the container, I can ssh into my container with:

```
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
```

However, when I try to ssh with:

```
ssh root@PUBLIC_IP -p 2222
```

It fails with a "Connection refused". (My security group in EC2 has port 2222 open on inbound on all IP space)

Answer (score 1):

If ssh works maybe scp will as well

```
scp root@${REMOTE_IP}:/tmp/remotefile  /tmp/localfile
```

Might be easier to create an aws Elastic Block Store volume which your container can mount then copy your data there

... or S3 bucket ... then copy locally

```
# ........ create s3 bucket

curr_bucketname=s3://${AWS_S3_BUCKET}


aws s3 mb ${curr_bucketname}

# ........ list buckets

aws s3 ls
```

then mount the S3 bucket to your container and once populated then

```
# ........ copy local dir to s3

aws s3 sync /opt/my/local/dir/of/files/  ${curr_bucketname}

# ... copy s3 bucket to populate (or just refresh) local dir


aws s3 sync ${curr_bucketname} /usr/tmp/local/dir
```